# May I benefit from MySQL partitions?

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have a database stored on a single SSD. I'm thinking that this enough tells me that I don't need partitioning, but still, I want to fully verify this.

My big table (let's call it `times`) has a column that represents a time of the day, stored as a dumb integer. For example `'12:07:31'` is stored as `120731`.

There is a foreign key from this table to another one (which we'll call `trips`); and this is linked to a last one (called `calendar`) which contains a date information.

Currently I have a script that runs every night and:

- filters the `calendar` table to retrieve only the rows of today
- from this, select all the information from the `times` that match only today
- from this, create a table for every hour+3

By 'every hour+3', I mean I have these tables:

- `times_00` => from 12am to 3am
- `times_01` => from 1am to 4am
- `times_02` => from 2am to 5am
- ...
- `times_19` => from 7pm to 10pm
- ...

So when I want to query `times`, I just query `times_10` between 10am and 11am; or `times_17` between 5pm and 6pm, etc.
This is MUCH faster because I go from 10M to <200k rows.

Now I have a feeling that I could benefit from partitioning, but how to partition:

- over the date: it's not a column of the table, but rather a column in a foreign table. Is it possible to use `JOIN`s in partition rules?
- over the time: I know I could partition using RANGE, but this won't get me overlapping partitions: 0-3, 1-4, 2-5...

Is it possible? Is it worth it?

---

You will [find here all the data](https://gist.github.com/BenoitDuffez/1acbca70b4aed29128ef) needed to reproduce my setup.

Here's the output of `./test.sh`:

```
stop_times:

real    0m0.487s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
stop_times_part:

real    0m0.707s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
stop_times_14:

real    0m0.127s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
```

The results are variable, but I observed a similar time for the first two methods (around 500ms), and a 4x faster time for the last method (around 125ms)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, You want to partition the "time" table row into different table. So that your query become fast. But I don't understand why u want to create 'every hour+3' table instead of 'every hour' table. If you generate every hour table then i think you have no problem of overlapping and every row of time table will be the foreign key of 'every hour' table.

Eg.

```
every_hour_12_03_2015_01 => for 12AM to 1 AM
every_hour_12_03_2015_02 => for 1AM to  2 AM
every_hour_12_03_2015_03 => for 2AM to  3 AM

:
:

every_hour_12_03_2015_24 => for 11PM to 12 AM
```

Comment: It's because I often query the rows that are valid only at a certain time and for the next 2 hours. So I have created tables that contains every 3 hours a day have, every hour. When searching at 10:18am I want to get all the data until 12:18pm, so I use a 3h table: times_10 that covers 10am-1pm. If I used every hour as you suggest, I wouldn't be able to search data after 11am when searching at 10:18. Unless I can query several parittions using the same statement? Can I?

Comment: U mean u want to list data of 3 hours? But suppose i access it at 10:10AM then which hours u want to see? whether 10AM-1PM or 9:AM-12PM?

Comment: At any time, I want to access the data at the time of request + 2 hours. So the minimum integer amount of hours to be queried is 3 (if you search at 8:59 you want to have 8-11 and not 8-10).

Comment: Can u suggest if user access at following time :-
1. 10:00 => ?
2. 10:30 => ?
3. 10:50 => ?
4. 10:59 => ?

which 3 hours u will show in the above cases?

Comment: The same for all: 10am-1pm, that's the shortest range that guarantees at least 2h for every query.

Comment: then make 'every hour' table and fire query for 3 tables at any time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72830/discussion-between-krishna-nandan-and-benoit-duffez).